# Is the conditional likelihood function I propose specified correctly?

Tags: probability, likelihood

Apologies if this question is rather vague and no further context is given. I am still in the process of developing the idea. I had come across a paper where for the regression $y_t=\beta x_{t}+\varepsilon_t$ for $t=1,\cdots,n$, the signs were defined as $S_t=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}^+}(y_t)$, for $t=1,\cdots,n$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is an indicator function. The likelihood function based on the independent signs for this regression was expressed as
\begin{equation}
P[S_1=s_1,\cdots,S_n=s_n\mid X]=\prod\limits_{t=1}^{n}P[S_t=s_t\mid X]
\end{equation}
where $X$ is an $n\times 1$ vector of explanatory variables - i.e. $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]'$.

In the case that I am currently considering, I have a regression of the form $y_t=\beta x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$ for $t=1,\cdots,n$ and wondered if mathematically it would be correct if the likelihood function based on the signs is conditioned only on the past information $X_{t-1}=[x_0,\cdots,x_{t-1}]$ - i.e.
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{t=1}^{n}P[S_t=s_t\mid X_{t-1}]
\end{equation}
as opposed to the entire process $X$ defined  earlier.

Comment: Denoting the covariate as $x_t$ or as $x_{t-1}$ does not modify anything in this model. One could as well denote it as $x_{t+1}$.

Comment: But would conditioning only on the past information as I have done so in the last equation incorrect? I wish to condition the probabilities iteratively only on the past information.

Comment: There is no past or future in these eqyations.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.